# How to extract URL from NSDataAsset?

Tags: swift, uikit, avaudioplayer, ios15, avkit

I have some MP3 files in my .xcassets folder. I can play them directly using `AVKit`'s `AVAudioPlayer(data: NSDataAsset(name: "foo")!.data).play()`. But, I want to extract the Metadata of the song using `AVPlayerItem`. But `AVPlayerItem`'s Initializer wants an `URL` as parameter.

How to extract the `URL` of an `NSDataAsset` ? I am using UIKit Framework btw.

Comment: ```let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "mp3")!

let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)``` Did u try this.

Comment: I will try now !

Comment: `Bundle.main.path(forResource:, ofType:)` is returning `nil` :-(

Comment: I tried with `Bundle.main.url(forResource:, ofType:)`. It is also returning `nil`

Comment: Your solution works when I have the file in the project folder. But, I am having the file in .xcassets folder

Answer (score 1):

I have some problem when wav or mp3 storage in `assets.xcassets`.
I fixed this issue by put all audio from `assets.xcassets` into project folder.
But I don't know what happen in it when use `assets.xcassets`.

Comment: Yes I too had the same problem. Since xcassets problem could not be solved. I put those mp3 files in project folder itself. Only then, I could get the URL of those mp3 files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).